# Making relative paths absolute in python

Tags: python, web-crawler, web-scraping

I want to crawl web page with python, the problem is with relative paths, I have the following functions which normalize and derelativize urls in web page, I can not implement one part of derelativating function. Any ideas? :

```
def normalizeURL(url):
    if url.startswith('http')==False:
        url = "http://"+url
    if url.startswith('http://www.')==False:
        url = url[:7]+"www."+url[7:]
    return url

def deRelativizePath(url, path):
    url = normalizeURL(url)

    if path.startswith('http'):
        return path
    if path.startswith('/')==False:
        if url.endswith('/'):
            return url+path
        else:
            return url+"/"+path
    else:
        #this part is missing
```

The problem is: I do not know how to get main url, they can be in many formats:

```
http://www.example.com
http://www.example.com/
http://www.sub.example.com
http://www.sub.example.com/
http://www.example.com/folder1/file1 #from this I should extract http://www.example.com/ then add path
...
```

Comment: As a side note I'd recommend reading the PEP8 to conform to best practices in coding style. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: awesome, thank you very much for coding style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend that you consider using [`urlparse.urljoin()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.urljoin) for this:

> Construct a full ("absolute") URL by combining a "base URL" (`base`) with another URL (`url`). Informally, this uses components of the base URL, in particular the addressing scheme, the network location and (part of) the path, to provide missing components in the relative URL.

Answer (score 3):

`from urlparse import urlparse`

And then parse into the respective parts.